# Prevent spam in XP system?

Tags: discord.js

I recently made an XP system in my Discord.js bot, and it works how it should, but getting XP is super easy since you can spam. Every message someone sends has a 50/50 % chance to give you XP.

How can I prevent spam in this system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a cooldown system, so someone can only get XP a maximum of one times per minute. You can do this by creating a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and checking if users are in the set before adding XP. If they are, cancel. If they're not, add the XP, add them to the set, and set a timer to remove them from the set.

For example:

```js
// declare this somewhere that it won't be reset every new message
const cooldowns = new Set()

...

// if they're on cooldown
if (cooldowns.has(message.author.id)) return;

// otherwise, add them to the cooldown
cooldowns.add(message.author.id);

...

// set a timer for 60000ms (60s)
setTimeout(() => cooldowns.remove(message.author.id), 60000)
```

Comment: is there a difference between new Set() and new discord.Collection()?

Comment: Yeah, a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) is a `Set` and a [`Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection) is a `Collection`

Comment: the bot just dies after the timeout is done, any ideas why?

Comment: nvm its cooldowns.delete() not cooldowns.remove(), thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd approach it is to keep a store of when you last gave a user any XP. You could do this in a database, but I'd use an object. Example:

```js
client.xpHistory = {};

client.on("message", message => {
    let author = message.member;
    let authorId = author.id;
    let historyKey = authorId + ":" + message.guild.id;
    let authorHistory = client.recentXP[historyKey];
    let msgSentAt = Math.floor(message.createdAt.getTime()/1000);
    
    if(typeof authorHistory === 'undefined') {
        //They haven't sent any messages since the bot restarted, so give them some
        client.recentXP[historyKey] = msgSentAt;
        let xpAmount = Math.floor(Math.random() * (25 - 10) + 10);
        //Give them that much XP, however you store your levels. Also this generates between 10 and 25 xp, change that how you like
        // The line below is set to let them have xp every 30 seconds, change that however you like
    } else if(msgSentAt >= client.recentXP[historyKey] + 30) {
        client.recentXP[historyKey] = msgSentAt;
        let xpAmount = Math.floor(Math.random() * (25 - 10) + 10);
        //Give them that much XP, however you store your levels. Also this generates between 10 and 25 xp, change that how you like
    }
});
```